# pipenv не может импортировать requests

Tags: python

Пишу в терминале - `pipenv install request`,
Получаю - `The 'requests>2.18.0' distribution was not found and is required by pipenv`. В чём может быть проблема? И что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Перед эти надо было выполнить `pipenv --python 3.6`